# How do I get Flash Builder to let me create run and debug configurations?

Tags: apache-flex, xdebug

My project got hosed somehow, and now I cannot create any configurations, so I can't run or debug it.  My project is open - I see the expanded sub-folders.  There are not compile errors showing up.  Under the project's properties I see Run/Debug Settings but the New button is greyed out.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to try:

1) Did you switch perspectives away from Flash or Flash Debug?  If so, move back to one of those perspectives and try again.

2) Did you recently install a new plugin that could be affecting things?

3) Try quitting and restarting Flash Builder.  Try quitting and restarting Flash Builder with the command line argument "-clean".  ( The latter sometimes fixes odd issues).

4) Try creating a brand new workspace and importing the old projects.

5) Can you bring up project properties?  Can you check to see if a main application is selected for the project?  It'd be odd for a project to lose one unless you deleted a file.  If there is no main application I don't believe you can create a run/debug profile.

6) Have you tried cleaning the project?  I believe clean is an option from the project menu.